# crontab refuse simple task which should always work

Tags: cron

I have a problem, crontab refuse to coop at all. 
I read a lot about it, and obviously this always should work:

```
* * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

I wait but no **env.output** appears.
What I find funny though is where crontab -e saves:

```
/tmp/crontab.i2ZQzh
```

I hope anyone has an idea, I am tired of starting my backups manually. I tired some backup software too, bt they doesn't work very well, some (small) disadvantages everywhere, I rely on rsync.

Thanks, regards, Dag

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include whose `crontab` are you editing, and how - which editor is being used, and how are you saving/exiting from it?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the user part, the correct syntax is:

```
* * * * * root env > /tmp/env.output
```

Replace the `root` with the user you want to run the command with.

Comment: Note that this is only the case for the system-wide cron jobs in `/etc/crontab` and `/etc/cron.d`; user crontabs (including root's, as accessed via `sudo crontab -e`) do not have this additional field

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your statement that you were using the command `crontab -e`.
You can verify the crontab entries by looking in '/var/spool/cron/crontabs' for the cron entries. (different nix flavors might have it in slightly different paths)

I would also suggest fully qualifying the path. Instead do:
    which env

```
/usr/bin/env
```

so change the entry to:

```
* * * * /usr/bin/env > /tmp/env.output
```

If this does not rectify your issue, you will need to specify which nix flavor you are using.

Comment: It seems I have an other problem. I must start this completly from the core. When I edit with crontab -e, I can but whatsoever in there, at save it only do what was in the firstmost entry which was "touch >/tmp/testing.txt " this appears all the time.

Comment: What unix version are you using?

Comment: Linux CD03B 4.4.0-87-generic #110~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 14:51:32 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Now I bring it to output a file, there where it should be (home/user/tst.txt), but the file is empty. Doesnt matter which command; it makes the file but doesn't execute the command.

Comment: I have a script /home/user/tst.sh:<br>

Comment: (I hitted enter, wrong). it does only date>tst1.txt in /home/user. tst.txt appears, empty, ok. tst1.txt does not appear, so in my opinion; script didn't run. Now I have read so much about crontab, that I am compltly confued. It is easier if i write my own little crontab to do jobs. write it in gambas: how late? hit-> do it. crontab seems to be like shooting ants wit canons. more difficult to use than other tools I have seen in linux

Comment: btw sorry about miswriting so much. my laptop keyboard isn't that z

Comment: young any more. i give it up.

Comment: From your description, that sounds like cron is firing (that is why file is created) but the command has issue.  When cron command is run, it has its own environment. (PATH, environment variables, etc). Your description sounds as if you are running the crontab as a regular user. It is possible that your environment is different for that user.  I would again recommend that you specify the fully qualified path for your command in the cron entry.  For example:
 ` * * * * * /bin/date > /home/user/tst.txt`

Also ensure that the cron daemon is running via 
`ps -ef | grep cron`

Comment: I will try that